# Listing files with specific endings in folder as variable, using python

Tags: python

I am trying to list files with specific ending ('.txt') in folder which was set as a variable, using python.

I tried to use glob.glob('userFolder/*.txt') in order to do it.

```
import os
import glob
userFolder='/homes/myFolder'
glob.glob('userFolder/*.txt')
```

I got an empty list.

Comment: It should rather be `glob.glob(userFolder + '/*.txt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `userFolder` in your `glob()` call is just part of the string value, it's not related to the variable with the same name. If it was, you could never use something like `print` or `os` or any other variable name directly in a string.

You could just use `+` to concatenate the variable value with the glob pattern:

```
text_files = glob.glob(userFolder + '/*.txt')
```

but the better method is to use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to handle path construction:

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(userFolder, '*.txt'))
```

Another option is to use the [`pathlib` module], which has its own glob support:

```
import pathlib

userFolder = pathlib.Path('/homes/myFolder')
text_files = userFolder.glob('*.txt')
```

Comment: Why "to use os.path.join()..." is better?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: it knows about the current platform conventions and knows how to join an arbitrary number of path elements or how to treat an absolute path in the added parts so you don't have to re-invent that wheel yourself.